# Add Days to predefined date

Tags: powershell, datetime

I'm looking for a way to add days to a predefined date in the format MM/DD/YYYY.

Basically I am trying to automate a process that looks at a predefined date and adds 30 days to it and then runs a series of commands.  All the searching around I've done has examples that use the current date, but none for predefined dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
([DateTime]'07/10/2015').AddDays(30)
```

First you cast a string representing your date to a .NET System.DateTime object then you use that object's `AddDays` method.  Note: when you are specifying type names to PowerShell you can omit the initial `System.` - if you want.

Comment: Thanks Keith, that worked.  I'm quite new to Powershell, so I am still learning quite a bit everyday.