# Powershell Subtract 1 day from variable date

Tags: powershell

How can I use a variable containing a date to act like get-date function in powershell? I have a variable $date containing 2016-09-08. I want to subtract one day from the $date. something like:

```
$date = "2016-09-08"
$date.AddDays(-1)
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Days to predefined date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351411/add-days-to-predefined-date)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"2016-09-08" is a string. You need to convert it to a datetime object. There are several ways to do so but below is an example of passing a string to the Get-Date cmdlet.

```
$date = Get-Date "2016-09-08"
$date.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details on all of the available options.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use a custom format string to get the date in whatever format you wish.

Answer (score 10):

Single line conversion and subtraction.

```
(Get-Date $date).AddDays(-1)
```

Answer (score 5):

This thread really helped me a lot and here's what I was trying to do. Sharing so others can see more things you can do with Get-Date and AddDays.

```
PS C:\Users\zzz> (Get-Date $date).AddDays(0).ToString("MMddyyyy")
07162019

PS C:\Users\zzz> (Get-Date $date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MMddyyyy")
07152019
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Mani Live's answer ... to use in a regular batch file:

```
for /F "usebackq" %%d in (`powershell -STA -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command "echo ((Get-Date).AddDays(-10)).ToString(\"yyyy-MM-dd\")"`) do set ten_days_ago=%%d
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is String. run `$date.gettype()` it will output string.

```
$date = "2016-09-08"
$date.gettype()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

to be able to use datetime functions you need a datetime variable.

```
$date = get-date("2016-09-08")
$date.gettype()
  IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Datetime                                   System.Object
$date.adddays(-1)
Wednesday, September 7, 2016 12:00:00 AM
```

then you can start using formatting of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also cast the string to a `datetime`:

```
$date = [datetime]"2016-09-08"
```

Or assign the string to a strictly-typed `datetime` variable:

```
[datetime]$date = "2016-09-08"
```